# Passing a value to and from triggered send email to custom LP

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to pass a custom variable value i.e. @process_publicationid (see code below) to the Triggered send Email  where i capture it .The email has a link leads to the custom LP. I pass variable value then to Custom LP.

Triggered send  :

```
 SET @process_publicationid= RequestParameter("listid")

 SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
   SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
      SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "21406")
   SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

   SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
   SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)  
   SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)

    SET @ts_col= CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_col, "Name", "publicationid")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_col, "Value", @process_publicationid)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_col)

   AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
   SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

   IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
       RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
   ENDIF
```

In the triggered email template : i use below to capture it :

```
SET @var_publicationid= RequestParameter("publicationid")
```

but i can't be able to pass the custom value i.e. publicationid to the email and thereby can't pass it to LP...

In the triggered email ,the `%%=v(@var_publicationid)=%%`  results nothing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing in`publicationid` as an attribute, you don't need to use `RequestParameter()` function to retrieve, and it should be a personalization string.

Try `%%publicationid%%` in your email template.

Comment: Does your triggered send data extension have the column to capture the publicationid?

Comment: I have publicationid column in profile management and as-well in DE.FYI, I selected all subscribers in subscriber management while creating Triggered send in ET.

Comment: If your passing in the attribute, then you should be able to use it as a personalization string. Whats the validation error?

Comment: thx.. my bad ..human error in validation... it worked!